# non https VssConnection with access token - disable required secure connection?

Tags: tfs

using TFS in our internal network, want to programatically check in changes with an access token, but get this: InvalidOperationException      Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server.  Is there a way to turn off requiring secure connection?

```
var basicCreds = new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, BuildUnitTestConstants.AccessToken);
var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(BuildUnitTestConstants.ProjectUri), basicCreds);
var sourceControlServer = connection.GetClient<TfvcHttpClient>();
```

Comment: Can you just use Windows authentication instead of a PAT? Enabling insecure Basic auth is a really bad idea, since credentials are transmitted in cleartext.

Comment: got it, this is at the end of our tfs build process it is a temporary token but I understand why they don't want to allow non-secured...

Answer (score 14):

Well, it is possible, albeit not recommended; I needed it as well, because internal IT department would not install TFS with HTTPS (sad story). Also, for testing scenarios it can come quite handy.

***As always YMMV and I'm not responsible for what happens when you use it when you shouldn't ;-) You have been warned.***

For one you could simply not use the .NET client API, but directly use `HttpClient` and manually put the PAT in the URL to access the REST API, e.g.:

```
 http://<WHATEVER>:<BASE64PAT>@<instance>/_apis/...
```

(Hence that the `tfx-cli` works nicely with PATs and non-HTTPS TFS instances, most likely because it does just that internally, not using the .NET client API of course - it is a node.js thing.)

If you want to stay with the .NET client API, you can create your own credentials class like so:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;

namespace Utilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Same as VssBasicCredential, but doesn't throw when URL is a non SSL, i.e. http, URL.
    /// </summary>
    /// <inheritdoc cref="FederatedCredential"/>
    internal sealed class PatCredentials : FederatedCredential
    {
        public PatCredentials()
            : this((VssBasicToken)null)
        {
        }

        public PatCredentials(string userName, string password)
            : this(new VssBasicToken(new NetworkCredential(userName, password)))
        {
        }

        public PatCredentials(ICredentials initialToken)
            : this(new VssBasicToken(initialToken))
        {
        }

        public PatCredentials(VssBasicToken initialToken)
            : base(initialToken)
        {
        }

        public override VssCredentialsType CredentialType => VssCredentialsType.Basic;

        public override bool IsAuthenticationChallenge(IHttpResponse webResponse)
        {
            if (webResponse == null ||
                webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Found &&
                webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Found &&
                webResponse.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return webResponse.Headers.GetValues("WWW-Authenticate").Any(x => x.StartsWith("Basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }

        protected override IssuedTokenProvider OnCreateTokenProvider(Uri serverUrl, IHttpResponse response)
        {
            return new BasicAuthTokenProvider(this, serverUrl);
        }

        private sealed class BasicAuthTokenProvider : IssuedTokenProvider
        {
            public BasicAuthTokenProvider(IssuedTokenCredential credential, Uri serverUrl)
                : base(credential, serverUrl, serverUrl)
            {
            }
            protected override string AuthenticationScheme => "Basic";
            public override bool GetTokenIsInteractive => this.CurrentToken == null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then create your VssCredentials using this class:

```
var credentials = new PatCredentials("", personalAccessToken);
var connection = new VssConnection(serverUrl, credentials);
```

(Shameless plug I use it in my [TfsInfoService](https://github.com/cklutz/TfsInfoService)).

Comment: Ok, that works. It hurts me to the core, but it works.

Comment: @jessehouwing Oh yes, "hurts me to the core" happens far to often in big corps that don't care about the essentials.

Answer (score 10):

Nowadays you don't need to use the workaround provided by @Christian.K

Simply set the following env variable:

```
VSS_ALLOW_UNSAFE_BASICAUTH=true
```

Source: code of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential`:

```cs
    protected override IssuedTokenProvider OnCreateTokenProvider(
      Uri serverUrl,
      IHttpResponse response)
    {
      bool result;
      if (serverUrl.Scheme != "https" && (!bool.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("VSS_ALLOW_UNSAFE_BASICAUTH") ?? "false", out result) || !result))
        throw new InvalidOperationException(CommonResources.BasicAuthenticationRequiresSsl());
      return (IssuedTokenProvider) new BasicAuthTokenProvider(this, serverUrl);
    }
```

To set the environment variable programatically:

```cs
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("VSS_ALLOW_UNSAFE_BASICAUTH", "true")
```

Comment: This simplify things

Comment: @Mugen it works. Thks. This should be the resolving answer. Please add the c# command to set env variable : Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("VSS_ALLOW_UNSAFE_BASICAUTH", "true");

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. The problem of enabling PAT over unsecured connections is that anyone could intercept the token easily and would be able to use it for their own purposes.

Either enable SSL on the TSF instance, this is highly recommended. Or use Windows Authentication to use a secure form of authentication to TFS over an unsecured channel.